# Run linear regression model on nested dataset after grouping (multiply imputed dataset)

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, r-mice

*I want to group nested (multiply imputed) dataset and then apply linear regression on each dataset. I have tried a number of approaches, including the map options (2) and the for loop (3). I have had no luck at all. I want the model results to look like results from `summary(mod1)`. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

```
    # get dependencies
    library(mice)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    # impute the boys dataset from mice package
    boys_imp <- mice(boys)
    
    
    # 1) I want to run a model like this on my multiply imputed dataset
    mod <- boys %>% 
      group_by(reg) %>% 
      do(tidy(
        lm(
          data=.,
          formula = wgt ~ bmi),
        conf.int = T))
    
    summary(mod1)
    
    # A tibble: 12 × 8
    # Groups:   reg [6]
    reg   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value conf.low conf.high
    <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
      1 north (Intercept)   -81.9      9.84      -8.32 2.48e-12  -101.      -62.3 
    2 north bmi             6.84     0.500     13.7  2.53e-22     5.85      7.84
    3 east  (Intercept)   -75.3      7.62      -9.89 3.21e-18   -90.4     -60.3 
    4 east  bmi             6.29     0.420     15.0  4.53e-32     5.46      7.12
    5 west  (Intercept)   -91.9      6.31     -14.6  2.48e-34  -104.      -79.4 
    6 west  bmi             7.17     0.347     20.7  3.49e-54     6.49      7.86
    7 south (Intercept)   -79.8      6.73     -11.9  1.83e-24   -93.1     -66.5 
    8 south bmi             6.47     0.373     17.3  1.63e-40     5.73      7.20
    9 city  (Intercept)   -92.0     13.9       -6.61 6.75e- 9  -120.      -64.2 
    10 city  bmi             6.95     0.757      9.18 1.39e-13     5.44      8.46
    11 NA    (Intercept)   -88.6     43.8       -2.02 2.92e- 1  -645.      468.  
    12 NA    bmi             6.46     2.89       2.24 2.68e- 1   -30.2      43.1 
    
    # 2) the map way --------------------------------------------------------
    mod_imp <- boys_imp %>%
      mice::complete("all")  %>%  
      map(group_by, reg) %>% 
      map(lm, formula = wgt ~ bmi) %>% 
      pool()
    
    summary(mod_imp)
    
    term   estimate std.error statistic       df p.value
    1 (Intercept) -85.473428 3.5511961 -24.06891 715.1703       0
    2         bmi   6.793622 0.1945322  34.92287 693.7835       0
    
    
    # 3) for loop way-------------------------------------------------------
    
    # nest the mids dataset
boys_imp2 <- boys_imp %>%
  mice::complete("all") 
dat1 <- replicate(length(boys_imp2), NULL) # preallocate same size
# run the for loop
for (i in seq_along(boys_imp2)) {
  
  dat1[[i]] <- boys_imp2[[i]] %>% 
    group_by(reg) %>% 
      do(lm(wgt ~ bmi, data = boys_imp2[[i]]))
}
    |==================================================================|100% ~0 s remaining     Error in `do()`:
      ! Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not lm.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.*
```

Comment: Your `boys_imp` is not a listy of datasets. You need to run lm on a dataset and not a vector a string etc

Comment: @onyambu this the format for multiply imputed datasets. I have to run models on each one separately then pool.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. This involve grouping the data by ID and variable of interest, subsequently I map lm on to the datasets. I then finish off with unnesting the data

```
boys_imp %>% 
mice::complete("long", include = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(.imp, reg) %>% 
  nest() %>%     
  mutate(lm_model = map(data, ~lm(bmi ~ phb, data = .))) %>% 
  group_by(reg) %>% 
  summarise(model = list(tidy(pool(lm_model),conf.int = T)))  %>% 
  unnest_wider(model) %>%  
    unnest(cols = c(term, estimate, std.error, 
                    statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high))

# A tibble: 30 × 16
   reg   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value conf.low conf.high           b          df       dfcom         fmi   lambda     m   riv  ubar
   <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> 
 1 north (Intercept)   19.3       0.332    57.9   0          18.6      19.9      
 2 north phb.L          5.10      0.678     7.53  1.81e-10    3.75      6.46       
 3 north phb.Q          1.25      0.800     1.56  1.24e- 1   -0.357     2.86      
 4 north phb.C         -0.430     0.882    -0.487 6.30e- 1   -2.25      1.39      
 5 north phb^4         -1.10      0.948    -1.16  2.57e- 1   -3.07      0.862        
 6 north phb^5         -0.156     1.08     -0.144 8.87e- 1   -2.41      2.10        
 7 east  (Intercept)   18.7       0.244    76.8   0          18.3      19.2        
 8 east  phb.L          4.83      0.509     9.48  4.44e-15    3.82      5.84        
 9 east  phb.Q          1.10      0.692     1.60  1.27e- 1   -0.343     2.55       
10 east  phb.C         -0.518     0.671    -0.772 4.49e- 1   -1.91      0.878    
# … with 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```